# Instancing a CGAL::Transformation of type Reflection

Tags: cgal

I am new to CGAL and I'm trying to instantiate a 2D `Reflection`.

Having defined `typedef CGAL::Aff_transformation_2<K> Transformation`,
which works for others `Transformations`, like :

```
Transformation rational_rotate(CGAL::ROTATION,  1, 100); //OK
Transformation translate(CGAL::TRANSLATION, Vector_2(-2, 0));//OK
```

I have a error message when trying this:

```
CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Cartesian<double>> LineR(A,B);
Transformation Reflection(CGAL::REFLECTION, LineR);
```

I've tried many `Kernels`, but I'm not sure the problem is in this direction.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Strange, it appears to be missing in the Cartesian kernels (but present in the wrapper). Homogeneous kernels go a bit further, but fail on what is likely a bug. Please file an issue on CGAL's github with a complete example (#include, typedef, we should be able to just copy-paste and compile to reproduce the issue).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your fast answer. I've added 2 files LAB.pro and LAB.cpp tagged on Tree : 1e7becd11f as you have asked.

Comment: Hi, please forget the tree, you may have a look at the issue #1216

Answer (score 0):

An exemple of an answer (no waranty):

```
Transformation getReflection(Line_2 droite)
{
    if( droite.is_degenerate() )
        std::cout<< "Droite dégénérée, tester avant l'appel de la fonction ..."<< std::endl;

    if( droite.is_vertical() )
    {
        double Xd = - droite.c()/droite.b();
        return Transformation(-1, 0, 2*Xd, 0, 1, 0, 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        double x = droite.x_at_y(0);
        Transformation translation (CGAL::TRANSLATION, CGAL::ORIGIN - Point_2(-x, 0) );
        double pente = droite.direction().dy()/droite.direction().dx();
        double angle = atan(pente);
        Transformation rotation(CGAL::ROTATION, sin(angle), cos(angle));
        Transformation comp = translation * rotation;
        return comp * Transformation(1, 0, 0, -1) * comp.inverse();
    }
}
```